# Read file path from utf-8 text file?

Tags: java, utf-8, filepath, backslash

I have a UTF-8 text file `example.txt` that contains:
`c:/temp/file.txt`

I read the file content using this method:

```
public static String fileToString(final File file, final String charset) throws AppServerException
    {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try
        {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(buffer);
        }
        catch (final FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new AppServerException(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            throw new AppServerException(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            FileHelper.close(fileInputStream);
        }

        try
        {
            return new String(buffer,charset);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
                throw new AppServerException(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Then I want to check if the file `c:/temp/file.txt` exists:

```
String content = fileToString("example.txt","UTF8");
File file = new File(content );
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

The `exits()` return false but the file actually exists.

If I change the encoding of example.txt to ANSI using notepad++, the exists() return true.

I already tried using:
`"c:\temp\file.txt"`, 
`"c:\\temp\\file.txt"`, 
`"c:\\\\temp\\\\file.txt"`, 
but without success.

I really need to use the file as UTF8. Do you have tips so the method exists() returns true?

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ probably puts a [Byte Order Mark](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in front of the file. This is unnecessary for UTF-8 and [Java does not interpret this sequence of three characters](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4508058).

Either use an editor that does not use a Byte Order Mark or write the string in ANSI if your filename does not contain any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Notepad++ has indeed a BOM option when selecting UTF-8. However, I am not selecting it :(. The problem is that the file contains other data and needs to be in UTF8...

Comment: You did not mention "other data" in your question. Could it be the case that the problem actually has something to do with this other data?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the file is not actually encoded as UTF-8. Can you print the actual byte values of the "\" characters in the file?

While you are at it: `InputStream.read(byte[] b)` is **not** guaranteed to read `b.length` bytes from the stream. You should be reading in a loop and checking the return value of the `read()` method in order to see how many bytes were actually read in each call.

Comment: The file is encoded with UTF-8. Using debug the path is "pretty": "c:/temp/file.txt" -> "c:/temp/file.txt"; "c:\temp\file.txt" -> "c:\\temp\\file.txt". But the exists() method always return false. Also using debug, the actual byte value return for the slash is 92. Its appears to be correct... :(

Comment: If you create the File object passing the literal string, instead of reading it from the file, does `exist()` return true?

Comment: Yes, passing the literal the file exists. I made this "hack": new String(content.getBytes(),"ASCII").substring(3);. Converting to ASCII, the first 3 char where "garbage". Doing this, it works... But I believe this is not the best aprroach. However, for now it works.

Comment: That certainly looks like a byte order mark. Can you print the value of these first three characters?